# How to remove 404 src errors using javascript after the page loads?

Tags: javascript, debugging, web

I have these src errors that I want to remove after the page loads. All the things have been marked with an underline or an arrow. I have tried this particular code , but nothing seems to work. can you help me pls?
[image: chrome console]

```
var ele = document.querySelectorAll('[src]')
Array.from(ele).forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener(
        'error',
        function (e) {
            item.remove()
        },
        true
    )
})
```

Comment: please post the code, not a screenshot, so that any intervention can be done with your code. You seem to have an unclosed class attribute in your image element

Comment: why would you be trying to remove the errors from the error output, rather than actually trying to update the code with correct URLs?

Comment: I am using an external api that lists all my youtube videos on my website. The 404 error comes from the videos that I have deleted, hence it is not able to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I contacted their support and it was an issue at their back-end. It is now fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function () {
      console.clear()
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to clear the console. I want to remove that grey image. That grey color image comes from the 404 error.

Comment: you can't prevent printing by the onerror function, unless you can intercept the browser throwing error events.
as far as I know, no such API has been found (if any, please let me know~).
So to solve the problem, you can only use some abnormal methods:
Don’t add the img tag, first request the picture yourself, if it is an error, append the img tag of the default picture, if it is successful, Just append the img tag.
Of course, I don’t think it is necessary to do this. . .

Answer (score 0):

### One workaround can be this by overriding img onerror.

```js
(function() {
    var allimgs = document.images;
    for (var i = 0; i < allimgs.length; i++) {
        allimgs[i].onerror = function() {
            this.style.visibility = "hidden"; //if you want hide
            this.remove(); //if you want to remove img tag
            console.clear(); //clear error from console
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Use this script at the end of your html.

Comment: the onerror event lister is not working. I dont know why.

Comment: Try this `<img src="..." onerror="this.style.display = 'none' "`

Comment: I am using an external api that lists all my videos here. I deleted some of my videos, hence it shows like this grey image. I want to remove them. I cannot add onerror attribute since, it loads the html after the page has loaded.